# How to avoid memory fragments?

Tags: c++, memory-management, mfc

I am developing a Visual C++ application. There is an object called CMyObject, as follows:

```
    typedef CMap<UINT, UINT, void *, void*> CMyMap;

    class CMyObject
    {
    public:
        CMyMap *m_pMyMap;   
        …Some other member variables…
    }
```

Some instances of CMyObject contains a map, some not. Therefore, to save memory, I define a pointer m_pMyMap and create a new CMap object only if the instance contains a map.

When I test my app, with the increase of the CMyObject instance, the number of memory blocks allocated and deallocated is also increasing. There are a lot of fragments during this period. To prevent this, I try to override the new/delete operator for CMyObject and CMyMap. But still find many fragments. So I try to trace into the MFC source codes for CMap. I find CMap is just using an internal buffer to store the hash table(m_pHashTable), as follows:

```
    m_pHashTable = new CAssoc* [nHashSize];
```

And for each hash entry, it uses:

```
    P = (CPlex *)new BYTE[sizeof(CPlex) + nMax *cbElement];
```

to allocate the spaces.

I believe these two may be the reason of the memory fragments and want to eliminate them. However, is there a way to override the new/delete operator for codes such as:

```
    new CAssoc* [nHashSize]
```

and

```
    (CPlex *)new BYTE[sizeof(CPlex) + nMax *cbElement]
```

so that the spaces will be allocated from my own memory manager instead of from the default heap?

Comment: First: What is wrong with those "memory fragments"? Why are you trying to avoid them? Why are you messing with memory management?

Comment: Has the feeling of a XY-problem...

Comment: This is what is bugging me "There are a lot of fragments during this period." what exactly do you mean by that and what are the problems you are facing because of that?

Comment: For Windows 7 and above, the LFH (low fragmentation heap) is used by default, so you may actually be making things worse by "fixing" this "problem". Just seeing numbers change in Task Manager (or whatever) is not necessarily indication of any serious issue.

Comment: An empty map doesn't take up much memory. Do you have lot's of these empty maps ? If it's a few thousands or so it's not even worth thinking about.

Comment: The problem is that after the application runs for some time, it reports "out of memory" error which makes me notice that the fragments has caused all memory being used up.